# Angular JS: can we set resolve or promise on controller which did not have route defined?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to fetch some data from server before controller get render.

I have found many answers for it with respect to `routeProvider`.

But my main **issue** is my controller does not bound with any route.

So is there any way to make this possible?

I have controller in following ways...

```
<!-- HERE I WANT TO BLOCK RENDERING TILL DATA GET LOAD   -->
<AppController>
    <ng-view> 
</AppController>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a `resolve` is what you are looking for, but if you are not using a routing table for this controller, you'll not have this option. Why not just resolve an asynchronous call in your controller, and set scope variables inside the callback. This is what I interpret your desire to await controller "rendering", whereas a `resolve` through a route table would await controller *instantiation*. Observe the following...

```
module.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/uri').then(function(response) {
        // set $scope variables here
    });

    console.log('executed first');
});
```

You could also set a variable to prevent the associated view from rendering if your data call is lengthy. This would prevent the UI from "dancing." Observe the following changes to the above example...

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-show="resolved"></div>
```

---

```
module.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/uri').then(function(response) {

        $scope.resolved = true; // show rendering
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kt84sxwL/) - simplified demo

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xwp4moss/) - demo `ng-if`

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried your solution it does not work with ng-if....So I have tried it with ng-show which I already know. But I was trying to find promise so that controller constructor does not get envoke before promise get success LIKE routeProvider has.

Comment: `ng-if` should work fine. are you resolving your data call correctly?

Comment: @PankajBadukale ahh nevermind, I see the issue. Will `ng-show` work? I'll update answer with a fiddle example

Comment: Yes, ng-show working....But it just solution to hide from user but developer  point of view. This is not a solution.

Comment: Then just `ng-if` a child `<div>` inside the parent element with your `ng-controller` option. I don't think you have many other options without using a `resolve` in route, so the solution seems pretty decent. I don't understand why you are not okay with the proposal

Comment: @PankajBadukale added a `ng-if` demo

Comment: Thanks first to create demo, but still i will say ng-if will not work....Try same with routing..As you can see, we have ng-view means routing view going to place there...try for that you will come to know why it will not work....Also this will tell you diff between ng-if and ng-hide/ng-show

Comment: @PankajBadukale wow, that fiddle was in **rough** shape. You had a syntax error for not injecting `$timeout` and were using angular 1.1. `ng-if` was not even in 1.1 !! So, after I fixed the error, upgraded the fiddle to 1.2, and included `ngRoute` as well as injected it into the app definition - everything is working perfectly, as I knew it would the first time around. I would appreciate if you accept the answer. [Here is your working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1y57vLh/)

Answer (score 0):

One idea will work
in html controller:

```
<p ng-if="notLoadedContent">Wait</p>

<div ng-if="!notLoadedContent">Content fetched</div>
```

And in Controller all controller is inside one function will start all, and the controller will be :

```
fetch(init)
$scope.notLoaded = true;
function init(){
$scope.notLoaded=false;
}
```

hope it help you